# Service Broker endpoint error in errorlog

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

Please can someone explain the meaning and source of the error message I'm getting in my errorlogs?

*The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.*

It is an AG cluster on WSFC with two nodes. SQL 2019

The error is logged every 15 minutes. From my research, I see that the fix is to create a service broker endpoint:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/service-broker-with-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

However, when I looked on the legacy system which is a SQL 2016 AG cluster, I don't see the message reported every 15 minutes nor does the system have service broker endpoints created when I run the command:

'''SELECT name, protocol_desc, type_desc, state_desc, port
FROM sys.tcp_endpoints

WHERE type_desc = 'SERVICE_BROKER';'''

I don't quite understand what the service broker endpoint is, nor do I know if it has any security implications if I create one.

I'd appreciate some guidance on this please. I will really like to stop this every 15 minutes message in the Primary replica's errorlog

Thank you.

Comment: You'll also get these during startup, what problem is it causing?

Comment: Feel free to get a XPERF/XE/TTT of the issue and I can take a look at it, but generally this will occur when there is a refresh of the listener due to a notification from the cluster.

Comment: @SeanGallardy thank you for your response. I'll have to Google what those are :-)

Comment: @SeanGallardy thank you for your response. I'll have to Google what those are :-) No, the message is not causing any problem other than that it is filling up the errorlog with reporting the message every 15 minutes. I'm not sure what you mean by listener getting refreshed from notification from the cluster, but this is  a new installation and not gone live yet.

Comment: WPR - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/windows-performance-recorder
XE - Taking a stack dump on the error when it occurs
TTT - Time travel tracing (via TTD recorder) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview

Comment: @SeanGallardy, thanks again for sharing your expertise and for your time, much appreciated.